# unable to mount disk in opensuse 13.2 KDE 5?

Tags: kde, opensuse, dolphin, plasma

I am Using Opensuse and Linux mint 17.1 and
when I open dolphin and open mint partition I get an error:

[image]

When I  run as `root`:

> $ sudo dolphin

I am getting this error:

> dolphin: cannot connect to X server

when I  run:

> kdesu dolphin

my dolphin **crashes**

**

> cat /etc/fstab  **OUTPUT** :-
>
> cat /etc/fstab UUID=3dd8b6c1-0aec-42f9-81da-da06ae9a330d swap swap
>   defaults 0 0 UUID=95fbd548-4c26-4314-8e63-2c18d201627c / btrfs
>   defaults 0 0 UUID=95fbd548-4c26-4314-8e63-2c18d201627c
>   /boot/grub2/i386-pc btrfs subvol=boot/grub2/i386-pc 0 0
>   UUID=95fbd548-4c26-4314-8e63-2c18d201627c /boot/grub2/x86_64-efi btrfs
>   subvol=boot/grub2/x86_64-efi 0 0
>   UUID=95fbd548-4c26-4314-8e63-2c18d201627c /opt btrfs subvol=opt 0 0
>   UUID=95fbd548-4c26-4314-8e63-2c18d201627c /srv btrfs subvol=srv 0 0
>   UUID=95fbd548-4c26-4314-8e63-2c18d201627c /tmp btrfs subvol=tmp 0 0
>   UUID=95fbd548-4c26-4314-8e63-2c18d201627c /usr/local btrfs
>   subvol=usr/local 0 0 UUID=95fbd548-4c26-4314-8e63-2c18d201627c
>   /var/crash btrfs subvol=var/crash 0 0
>   UUID=95fbd548-4c26-4314-8e63-2c18d201627c /var/lib/mailman btrfs
>   subvol=var/lib/mailman 0 0 UUID=95fbd548-4c26-4314-8e63-2c18d201627c
>   /var/lib/named btrfs subvol=var/lib/named 0 0
>   UUID=95fbd548-4c26-4314-8e63-2c18d201627c /var/lib/pgsql btrfs
>   subvol=var/lib/pgsql 0 0 UUID=95fbd548-4c26-4314-8e63-2c18d201627c
>   /var/log btrfs subvol=var/log 0 0
>   UUID=95fbd548-4c26-4314-8e63-2c18d201627c /var/opt btrfs
>   subvol=var/opt 0 0 UUID=95fbd548-4c26-4314-8e63-2c18d201627c
>   /var/spool btrfs subvol=var/spool 0 0
>   UUID=95fbd548-4c26-4314-8e63-2c18d201627c /var/tmp btrfs
>   subvol=var/tmp 0 0 UUID=5d93bc1c-24c5-40ee-bcbc-876b5a4d433b /home xfs
>   defaults 1 2 UUID=95fbd548-4c26-4314-8e63-2c18d201627c /.snapshots
>   btrfs subvol=.snapshots 0 0

Comment: sudo resets the environment by default so the DISPLAY environment variable is not set when dolphin is run. In addition, mounting using dolphin as root will not allow you to access the files that are not accessible as normal users in the filesystem.

Comment: When *not* running as root, I think you need more info about the error dolphin returns. Is there a log file with more info, or does running dolphin in a terminal show anything useful? And did this ever work fine, "before" something happened? Is the drive being mounted even in fstab?